# How to get data from Tensor object in c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

I am running a Tensorflow model return a 3D array as output, and I couldn't get that array of data from the tensor.

I did print the shape of the output of the model without any problem.

```
std::vector<tf::Tensor>        outputs;
 auto start_inference = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 _status = _session->Run({inputs}, {"k2tfout_0", "k2tfout_1"}, {}, &outputs);
if (!_status.ok())
 {
   std::cerr << _status.ToString() << std::endl;
   return 0;
 }
unsigned int output_img_n0 = outputs[0].shape().dim_size(0);
unsigned int output_img_h0 = outputs[0].shape().dim_size(1);
unsigned int output_img_w0 = outputs[0].shape().dim_size(2);
unsigned int output_img_c0 = outputs[0].shape().dim_size(3);
```

That code worked without any error and showed the shape of the array. But still, I couldn't get the data from the outputs Tensor object.

The only function is worked is

```
float_t *plant_pointer = outputs[1].flat<float_t>().data();
```

But it destroy the array shape.
EDIT:
The output shape of the tensor is [num,high,width,channel] === [1,480,600,3]. So, the output is an image of semantic segmentation image of the model. I just want the image part without the first dim which always be 1.

Answer (score 7):

The [`tensorflow::Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor) class allows you to access its contents through several methods. With `.flat` you get a flattened version of the array, `.tensor` gives you a full [Eigen tensor](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support), and then there are a few other like `.vec`/`.matrix` (like `.tensor` with number of dimensions fixed to 1 or 2) and `flat_inner_dims`/`flat_outer_dims`/`flat_inner_outer_dims` (gives you a tensor with some dimensions collapsed). You can use the one that suits you best. In this case, for example if you want to print all the values in the tensor, you can use `.flat` and compute the corresponding offset or use `.tensor` if you know that the number of dimensions is 4:

```
std::vector<tf::Tensor>        outputs;
auto start_inference = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
_status = _session->Run({inputs}, {"k2tfout_0", "k2tfout_1"}, {}, &outputs);
if (!_status.ok())
{
  std::cerr << _status.ToString() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
unsigned int output_img_n0 = outputs[0].shape().dim_size(0);
unsigned int output_img_h0 = outputs[0].shape().dim_size(1);
unsigned int output_img_w0 = outputs[0].shape().dim_size(2);
unsigned int output_img_c0 = outputs[0].shape().dim_size(3);

for (unsigned int ni = 0; ni < output_img_n0; ni++)
{
  for (unsigned int hi = 0; hi < output_img_h0; hi++)
  {
    for (unsigned int wi = 0; wi < output_img_w0; wi++)
    {
      for (unsigned int ci = 0; ci < output_img_c0; ci++)
      {
        float_t value;
        // Get vaule through .flat()
        unsigned int offset = ni * output_img_h0 * output_img_w0 * output_img_c0 +
                              hi * output_img_w0 * output_img_c0 +
                              wi * output_img_c0 +
                              ci;
        value = outputs[0].flat<float_t>()(offset);
        // Get value through .tensor()
        value = outputs[0].tensor<float_t, 4>()(ni, hi, wi, ci);
        std::cout << "output[0](" << ni << ", " << hi << ", " << wi << ", " << ci << ") = ";
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that, although these methods create [`Eigen::TensorMap`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1TensorMap.html) objects, which are not really expensive, you may prefer to call them only once and then query the tensor object multiple times. For example:

```
// Make tensor
tf::TTypes<float_t, 4>::Tensor outputTensor0 = outputs[0].tensor<float_t, 4>();
// Query tensor multiple times
for (...)
{
    std::cout << outputTensor0(ni, hi, wi, ci) << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to obtain a pointer to the data of the tensor (for example to build another object from the same buffer avoiding copies or iteration), you can also do that. One option is to use the `.tensor_data` method, which returns a `tensorflow::StringPiece`, which is in turn a [`absl::string_view`](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/strings), which is just a polyfill for [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). So the `.data` method of this object will give you a pointer to the underlying byte buffer for the tensor (note the warning in the documentation of `.tensor_data`: "the underlying tensor buffer is refcounted", so do not let the returned object be destroyed while you use the buffer). You can therefore do:

```
tf::StringPiece output0Str = outputs[0].tensor_data();
const char* output0Ptr = output0Str.data();
```

This however gives you a pointer to `char` so you would have to cast it to use it as float. It should be safe, but it looks ugly, so you can let Eigen do that for you. All Eigen objects have a `.data` method that returns a pointer of its type to the underlying buffer. For example:

```
const float_t* output0Ptr = outputs[0].flat<float_t>().data();
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. So, there isn't a direct way to get the array data, which is an image, from the Tensor Object; I need a For loop to go over it and read it.

Comment: @Zaher88abd No, you can also obtain a pointer to the data, if that is what you mean. I have extended the answer explaining that.

Comment: Thanks again for your helping. And I tried in many ways to read the array but I failed, so, may ask you to put an example for how I can read the image form ```outputs[1].matrix<float_t>().data();``` , which should be in this dims ```float img[output_img_h0][output_img_w0][output_img_c0]```. after removing the first dimension the batch size.

Comment: @Zaher88abd You didn't describe `outputs[1]` in your question. Is it a matrix (2-dim tensor)? What are the dimensions, and how can it represent an image with multiple channels? I'm still not sure what exactly you want to do with your tensor data...

Comment: I edited the question and added the shape the output[1] which is [1,480,600,3] === [m,h,w,c] where c is channels of the image. Thanks for helping, I appreciated.